# Cannot run JModelica demos on Windows

Tags: jmodelica

I install the JModelica.org following the instruction of UsersGuide on Windows. However, I failed to run the cstr_casadi demos. Do you know what is the reason? I'll appreciate it. Here is the link of UsersGuide[UsersGuide](https://jmodelica.org/downloads/UsersGuide.pdf)

Comment: Did you see any errors?

Comment: I can run the fmi_bouncing_ball demo well. However, when I run the cstr_casadi. It shows an error cannot import name vdp.

Comment: And if I open ipython from JModelica org-SDK, tying from pyfmi.examples import fmi_bouncing_ball, it shows an error no module named pyfmi.examples.